# Jquery close dropdown on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, user-experience

I'm trying to create a `<select>` replacement that mimics all of `<select>`s functionality, but can be custom styled and use icons.
My problem is i can't seem to get `focusout` to hide the options. As of now `focusout` trigger the same thing when tabbing/arrowing the list items as when you tab/click outside.

**Generated HTML**

(idd = icon-drop-down)

```
<div class="idd-wrapper">
  <button>Select text</button>
  <ul id="idd-ul">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-apple"></span>
        <span class="idd-text">Apple</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    [...]
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#idd-ul a').each(function(e) {
  $(this).on('focusout', function(e) {
    //Trying different if statements...
    if($('#idd-ul a').is(':focus')){
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $('#idd-ul').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

CodePen here [Accessible  dropdown with icons](http://codepen.io/DanielGoransson/pen/ezuFo)

Comment: working just fine. you have commented out the line `$idd_ul.hide()`!

Comment: Same here. Works fine in Chrome

Comment: @abhitalks but the value in select is not getting changed when a value is being selected.

Comment: You don't have to wrap all these bindings inside each loop

Comment: Sorry for not specifying... It do wrong thing when tabbing/arrowing the list, as well as when you mouse click/tab outside of the list.

Comment: @abhitalks So, unfortunately, it's not working properly.